# Rails: using ActiveAdmin, what's with the views of my controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

this has maybe an obvious answer, but I just want to get sure and learn how to do things in the correct way.

I just starting to use ActiveAdmin on Rails, and now obviously I don't want more the *new* and *edit* views generated by scaffold command. Should I just delete those views and the methods (*new-edit-create-update-destroy*) in the controller file?

Thanks!

Comment: the last two lines are misleading and not so clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, if the views and actions added are not being used. Then you can remove those. Generally scaffold is not suggested as it creates lot of unnecessary files which may never be used in the application.